# Image fliker once list of image updates by usening setState()

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have list with image url for each element and otehr parameter as well.Now i have added on more parameter in each of element "isFavorite" (true/false), by default set "false".

Now i click on image call favorite/unfavorite api and success on API, update list like isFavorite: true and if true then set it false for particular element.

So, Now problem is , Once i set favorite / unfavorite flag and update my list by using setState() image will fliker or blink.

Hear image url not changed.

I have also checked "KeyExtracter" key is unique for all element and key is not changed after list update.

I have also set source & defaultSource of image property but still image will fliker.

Please check below code

```
            <FlatList
                ref={(ref) => { this.flatListRef = ref; }}
                data={this.state.articles}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (<Article
                    navigation={this.props.navigation}
                    isMemberLoggedIn={this.state.isMemberLoggedIn}
                    article={item}
                    addFavoriteCallBack={() => this.onPressAddFavoriteArticles(item.id)}
                    removeFavoriteCallBack={() => this.onPressRemoveFavoriteArticles(item.id)}
                />)}    
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                ------
            />

         
         // Add favorite
         if (response) {
            let tempArticles = this.state.articles.map((ele, i) => {
                if (ele.id === articleId) {
                    ele.isFavorite = true;
                }
                return ele;
            })
            this.setState({ articles: tempArticles });
        }

       
        // Remove favorite
         if (response) {
            let tempArticles = this.state.articles.map((ele, i) => {
                if (ele.id === articleId) {
                    ele.isFavorite = false;
                }
                return ele;
            })
            this.setState({ articles: tempArticles });
        }
```

Please help if any one have solution or any thinhg else.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a try to create the custom component with React.memo or useMemo react hook it can help you with the re-render and return memoized components.

Check out the below example.

[React Memo Example](https://dmitripavlutin.com/use-react-memo-wisely/)

Comment: Thanks jignesh, i have try this one but it is not work

Comment: I can see you are mutating the state so please use spread to immutate the data might help you..